# Injecting a singleton into JAX-RS (Jersey) resources, as a Tomcat servlet

Tags: rest, servlets, dependency-injection, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm trying to build a RESTful web service. This component is an addition to an existing Tomcat 7 web application that contains several Servlets already. I'm using Jersey 2.25.

I need to instantiate a few components (objects) that are related to the existing system. I wish to do that once, while the application loads - and than read them from each Resource.

My current classes are:

```
@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        packages("plc_webservice.PersonResource");

        register(new MyBinder());
    }
}

public class MyBinder extends AbstractBinder{

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(new MyService()).to(MyService.class);
    }
}
```

This is the class that I want to use as a singleton:

```
public class MyService {
    String name;

    public MyService() {
        name = "John";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    } 
}
```

And a resource:

```
@Path("Person")
public class PersonResource {


    @Inject
    private MyService service;    

    @GET
    public String test() {
        String result = "Hello!";

        return result;
    }
}
```

I can't figure out why am I getting this exception:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: A MultiException has 3 exceptions. 
>   They are:
>   1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at
>   SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=MyService,parent=PersonResource,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1688478701)
>   2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of plc_webservice.PersonResource errors were found
>   3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on plc_webservice.PersonResource
>
> org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:489)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
>   root cause
>
> A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:
>   1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at
>   SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=MyService,parent=PersonResource,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1688478701)
>   2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of plc_webservice.PersonResource errors were found
>   3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on plc_webservice.PersonResource
>
> org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Collector.throwIfErrors(Collector.java:89)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:250)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:162)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2022)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:774)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:737)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:707)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:172)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:284)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:318)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
>   root cause
>
> org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no
>   object available for injection at
>   SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=MyService,parent=PersonResource,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,1688478701)  org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:75)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:212)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:235)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:162)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2022)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:774)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:737)
>     org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:707)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:172)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:284)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:318)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
>     org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a CDI question. Do you have beans.xml defined? Also, if you want `MyService` to be a singleton, I think you want to annotate it with [@ApplicationScoped](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbk.html).

Comment: Or with @Singleton and add it to a binding

Comment: I changed the way in which I construct the ResourceConfig object and it worked. I think it was some kind of a build problem. The code is the same and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

First of all injected resources(beans) **and Jersey Endpoint class(point of injection)** must be CDI-Aware. It must be detecteable by CDI. We can use bean-discovery-mode="all" - then CDI scan ALL classes  or 
bean-discovery-mode="annotated" and MARK our class with PROPER annotation: from here : [Bean defining annotations](https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#default_bean_discovery). I prefer@Dependent or @RequestScoped

Then we must use Jersey Extension

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-cdi1x-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>{version}</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

`

to connect CDI with HK2 discovery mechanism.
Here is  [Official oracle Guideline](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs-advanced004.htm)